# .htaccess with subdomains and GET requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

When a user accesses **test.domain.co.uk**, I would like to show them the page at **channels/index.php?url=test** where **test** can be anything.

I have this working with the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.+\.domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{HTTP_HOST}$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.domain\.co\.uk/? channels/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

However, I would also like it to work if you called **http://test.domain.co.uk/login/**

And it would show you **channels/index.php?url=test&page=login**

I have tried a few ways and it just shows it as if it is **?url=test**

Comment: Would you like to rewrite these 2 specific URLs only and leave all other unchanged? Most probably you have other resources like images, css, js files...

Comment: That is fine, I can sort that after. Just the issue of it not working this far.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.domain\.co\.uk(.+)$ channels/index.php?url=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

to the end of your rules. And add a `$` to the pattern of your last rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.domain\.co\.uk/?$ channels/index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Then to keep from looping, add this to the top:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Tried this too, but the addition of $ creates an internal server error?

Comment: **Correction:** This makes the GET value of page equal channels/index.php

Comment: @TomWhale See the edit, add another rule to the top of your rules to prevent looping

Comment: Works, almost perfectly, just adds 2 slashes on the PAGE value? Tried using (.+^[^/]*$) but it says that test.domain.co.uklogin can't be found

Comment: @TomWhale I don't see any slashes when I'm testing. Maybe try changing the last regex to: `^(.+)\.domain\.co\.uk(.+?)/*$`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^((?!channels/index\.php).*)$ /channels/index.php?url=%1&page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Tried something similar to this, and just gives you an internal server error.

Error log "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error"

Comment: Thanks again, but "RewriteCond: cannot compile regular expression '(?L^|&)url=[^&]+'"

Comment: oh sorry, it was a typo, fixed it now. Try updated rule.

Comment: Works for if there is a parameter after the URL such as login/ but the GET request for page becomes index.php otherwise?

Comment: Added a slash before $ on the last line and it works, however, if you go to test.domain.co.uk it goes to the main index.php instead of channels/index.php

Comment: oh that is because `.+` instead of `.*`, see edited code now.